# My keyboard doesn't work after sleep mode

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, keyboard, suspend

I have a problem for some weeks with my keyboard when I leave sleep mode: the last doesn't want to work.

Below, I put the piece of line that appear when I leave sleep mode, just before the log screen arises:

```
[9842.304965] ACPI error : Needed [Integer/String/buffer], found [Reference] 000000006951a5e9 (20170831/exresop-505)
[9842.305009] ACPI Exception : AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [LEqual] (20170831/dswexec-461)
[9842.305056] ACI Error : Method parse/execution failed \_SB.BAT1._BTP, AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170831/psparse-550)
```

I reach to make it works again by loging in with an other user session previously closed (or my session if I closed it before switching into sleep mode or by loging in a first time, closing it and loging in again) thanks to the virtual keyboard (and finally, loging in to my own user session when I find back the keyboard)- I hope you understand my problem and understand that it's not a really practical way to log in and fix the problem and it's not really fast...

I tried to change my grub settings like that:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash atkbd.reset i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

`

But it doesn't seem to have any effects.

Last, the error appeared when I upgraded my distribution from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. But I had already had this problem with my ubuntu 16.04.

Good night, Albert